# what is the difference between Helm ,helm and tiller in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Helm is a tool for managing Kubernetes charts. Charts are packages of pre-configured Kubernetes resources.Some time for beginner its very confusing So what is basic difference between Helm,helm and tiller.?

Comment: The definition of [Tiller](https://helm.sh/docs/glossary/#tiller) in the "glossary" section of the Helm documentation is probably a good starting point.  Beyond the initial installation it's not usually a component you have to worry about directly.

Answer (score 13):

Helm is made of two components: the CLI binary named `helm` that allows you to perform communication with a remote component, named `tiller` that lives inside your Kubernetes cluster that is responsible to perform patches and changes to resources you ask to manage.

In fact, once deployed `tiller` using the command `helm init`, you can notice a new *Deployment* resource (commonly named `tiller-deploy`) running inside `kube-system` namespace.

The real question should be *why to use Tiller and not interacting directly with Kubernetes API*?

As usual, it is a matter of [security concerns](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/docs/securing_installation.md), recapped by these list items:

```
- Role-based access control, or RBAC
- Tiller's gRPC endpoint and its usage by Helm
- Tiller release information
- Helm charts
```

Comment: In Helm version 3 (currently in beta), [Tiller goes away and `helm` uses the Kubernetes API directly](https://v3.helm.sh/docs/faq/#removal-of-tiller).

Comment: Obvously the question was regarding Helm2 due to Tiller stuff